# C++ Class isn't returning the correct value of my private variable

Tags: c++, class, function, variables

Im trying to get this program to take the users input and put that into a public function and assign it to the privateVariable, then I want it to return the value of privateVariable to main() and output it to the screen, but all it displays is the value of an undefined int ( -858993460 ). What logical problem am I having here ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyClass
{

    private:
        int privateVariable;

    public:
        int userVariable;

    void setVariable(int userVariable)
    {  
        privateVariable = userVariable;             
    } 

    int getVariable()
    {
        return privateVariable;                     
    } 

};

int main()
{
    int userVariable;
    cin >> userVariable;

    MyClass object1;
    MyClass object2;

    object1.setVariable(userVariable);        
    object2.getVariable();                   

    cout << object2.getVariable();            

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you set the variable for `object1` and try to retrieve it from `object2`? Either you missed the concept of `static` variables or you made a type, I would guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting in `object1` and getting from `object2`. `object1` and `object2` are different objects. As variable in `object2` is not set, you get a garbage value.

And I see no use of public `userVariable` in `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the variable. You call `setVariable` on `object1` and `getVariable` on `object2`, so the member of `object1` remains uninitialized.

```
object1.setVariable(5); // object1.privateVariable = 5
                        // object2.privateVariable -> still uninitialized
object2.getVariable();  // returns uninitialized variable
```

For this to work, depending on what you want:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
   static int privateVariable;
//......
}
```

This way, privateVariable will be a class-scoped member, not instance-scoped. That means it has the same value for all instances of the class (and even if instances were not created). This also means you can make both your functions static:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
   static int privateVariable;
public:
   static void setVariable(int userVariable)
   {  
      privateVariable = userVariable;             
   } 

   static int getVariable()
   {
      return privateVariable;                     
   } 
};
```

and you can call the methods without instances:

```
MyClass::setVariable(5); //MyClass.privateVariable = 5;
MyClass::getVariable(); //returns 5
object1.getVariable(); //returns also 5
```

Another option is, if you don't want static members, to set the member for both objects:

```
object1.setVariable(5); // object1.privateVariable = 5
                            // object2.privateVariable -> still uninitialized
object2.setVariable(5); //object2.privateVariable = 5
object2.getVariable();  // returns 5
```

Or, you could define a constructor and set the variable there:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
   static int privateVariable;
//......
public:
   MyClass()
   {
      privateVariable = 5;
   }
}
```

With this, every object you create will have the member initialized to 5.

Answer (score 0):

object2 does not have your variable initialized as you set it on object1, the code you posted would only work if privateVariable was static.